# I just started playing CoD Advanced Warfare and I can't get past Traffic mission

Tags: ps4, call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

I complete the quicktime event with the jeep and then jump back on to the roof of the bus. However the moment I land on the bus the mission ends saying "KVA escaped with the hostage"

I've tried restarting but same thing, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: More info: I've been told that afterwards an enemy helicopter should appear - it doesn't that's when the mission ends

Comment: Are you sure you are doing it fast enough?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the [IGN Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare Walk Through](http://au.ign.com/wikis/call-of-duty-advanced-warfare/Traffic):

> Complete the QTE's to leap onto the roof of a passing bus, then take out all of the hostile cars while leaping from buss to bus. After falling off the bus, eliminate the other cars and complete the QTE to take out the last enemy vehicle. Leap back to the bus and eliminate the chopper that appears overhead.

If you have an issue with something not spawning, there is not much you can do about that other then restarting the level. Even on the hardest difficulty this should not be too bad, given its such an early level.

You will find a full walk through to the level, as well as a video play through, at the link I provided.